# Javascript Generate Array of Hours in the Day Starting with Current Hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date

Hi I'm trying to generate an array of every hour of the day. However, I want it to start with the current hour.

For example,

**if the current time is 2:00 pm, the array should start:**

['1400', '1500', '1600', 1700', '1800', '1900', '2000', '2100', '2200', '2300']

**instead of**

['0000', '0100', '0300', '0400', '0500', '0600', '0700', '0800', '0900', '1000', '1100', '1200', '1300', '1400', '1500', '1600', 1700', '1800', '1900', '2000', '2100', '2200', '2300']

Comment: If you are trying, where's your code?

Comment: use `.filter` with `parseInt` and `(new Date().getHours())` to filter all hours before the current hour of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straight-forward. See comments inline:

```js
var result = [];                      // Results will go here
var nowHour = new Date().getHours();  // Get current hour of the day

// Loop from current hour number to 23
for(var i = nowHour; i < 24; i++){
  result.push(i + "00");  // Put loop counter into array with "00" next to it
}

console.log(result); // show results
```

Comment: Hi @scott-marcus , if I wanted to skip an hour ahead, do you know how I can do that? Let say instead of starting with the current hour, I want to skip 1 hour ahead. 

For example, it's 5pm, so I want to start the array at 
['1800', '1900', '2000', '2100', '2200', '2300']

Comment: @lotsonj Yes, that's simple. Instead of `for(var i = nowHour; i < 24; i++){`, you'd change the loop to: `for(var i = nowHour + 1; i < 24; i++){` to simply start one more than the current hour.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fill` and `map` of `Array.Prototype`
Something like below.

```
Array(24-new Date().getHours()).fill().map((e,i)=>i+new Date().getHours());
```

```js
var currHour=new Date().getHours();
console.log(Array(24-currHour).fill().map((e,i)=>i+currHour+"00"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @yajiv, that's exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi @yajiv, both you and Scott gave good answers and I really appreciate the help. I saw yours before his. I'm sorry I checked and unchecked your answer. I saw his answer later and just thought his was much closer to what I was looking for with the for loop included. I still appreciated your answer tho and voted it up. I which StackOverflow allowed choosing more than one answer as the best. I would have marked yours as well. Sorry

Comment: This is a really inefficient algorithm. It creates numerous unnecessary Date objects, an Array that is essentially just used as a counter and still needs additional processing to add a leading zero to hours before 10:00.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done reasonably efficiently in a single statement, including leading zeros on hours before 10:00, and generically using *Array.from* with an optional callback, e.g.

```js
console.log(
  Array.from(Array(24-new Date().getHours()),(x,i)=>('0'+(23-i)).slice(-2)+'00').reverse()
);
```

Unfortunately it still creates 2 arrays, the first is an empty array of the required length that is then used to generate the second array with the required values, so not much of a performance hit.

If there was a *forEvery* method that didn't skip non-existant properties in the same way *from* doesn't, it could be one with just one Array (just like a for loop does).