# How to create array of hours starting from specific hour with specific minutes interval

Tags: angular, typescript, time

Using typescript(Angular) I want to have list of all hours of day with minutes difference as passed and less than the time passed.

Below is my current code:

typescript file

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dayaHours =   this.getHours("15", "10:00:00")
  }
    getHours(step, yourTime) {

    const slotArray = [];
    const startMinutes = yourTime ? this.howManyMinutesPassed(yourTime) : 0;
    const parsedSlotSize = parseInt(step.toString(), 10);


    for (let i = startMinutes; i <= 24 * 60; i += parsedSlotSize) {
      slotArray.push({
        time: this.convertMinutesToTimeFormat(i),
        minutes: i,
      });
    }

    return [...slotArray];
  }

  howManyMinutesPassed(time) {
    const [hour, minutes] = time.split(':').map((value) => parseInt(value, 10));
    return hour * 60 + minutes;
  }

  public convertMinutesToTimeFormat(mins) {
    let h: string | number = Math.floor(mins / 60);
    let m: string | number = mins % 60;
    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
    return `${h}:${m}:00`;
  }


  formatTime(time)
  {

    const H = +time.substr(0, 2);
    const h = H % 12 || 12;
    const ampm = (H < 12 || H === 24) ? " AM" : " PM";
    return h + time.substr(2, 3) + ampm;

  }
```

HTML code:

```
<div *ngFor="let time of dayaHours"><p>{{formatTime(time.time)}}</p></span><br><br></div>
```

I want to restrict to add 24:00 into my array when selected time is greater than 12:00 AM.

Please refer [Demo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lc2agx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

UPDATE:

Using above code:

If I use getHours function

```
getHours('10', '12:00')
```

> Output: [**12:00 AM**, 12:10 AM, 12:20 AM, 12:30 AM, 12:40 AM, 12:50
>   AM, 1:00 AM......so on, 11:00PM, 11:10 PM, 11:20 PM, 11:30 PM, 11:40
>   PM, 11:50 PM, **12:00AM**]

In above case I don't want to have 12:00 AM again.
Same happen if I pass time 10:00 to getHours function etc.

Similar question [javascript-generate-array-of-hours-in-the-day-starting-with-current-hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245033/javascript-generate-array-of-hours-in-the-day-starting-with-current-hour)

Thanks

Comment: do you want something like "15 hours Minutes passed 10" from a given start time

Comment: Hi @PawanJangid, I want to have array of all hours of day (24 hours) but minutes difference can be selected by user (10minutes, 20 minutes, 15 minutes, 30, 45, 60)
I am updating post to show desired results.

Comment: Can try for (let i = startMinutes; i < 24 * 60; i += parsedSlotSize)

Comment: @PawanJangid That is what I am already doing.